# Roughly 3 things I need to do openGL 2.0 is stumping me

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I need to know roughly 3 things to get started using OpenGL 2.0 ES.

1. How to set the viewport for 2d and order my textures front to back
2. How to load a texture as a 2d image.
3. How to move that image (translate it).

Three (edit): I could see as being a simple shader and vertex attrib being set, however.

Comment: Hey @KnowMonster, check this out: http://opengles2learning.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/first-experience-with-opengl-es2-on_15.html

Comment: That looks like a good blog to help out man, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) and check out the accompanying samples in the SDK (download the samples from the SDK manager and search for `StaticTriangleRenderer.java`).

That said, while knowledge of the underlying plumbing is critical for anything serious, I suggest you look into `libgdx` and other frameworks. `Libgdx` in particular makes development *really* easy and takes care of the annoying bits for you. You also get (some) cross-platform compatibility, though I can't attest to its quality.

Comment: Thanks. I need some experience with the underpinnings, but I'm considering Libgdx

Comment: I'd go and look at the API demo samples to get you started. You should also realise that most things in the full OpenGL 2 are also in ES (most notably, quads are missing). Last piece of advice - don't bother with OpenGL 1.x. It's a really small part of the market and a really broken API on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
// setup and load the texture, PSEUDOCODE
```

see here: [2 Textures, 1 Shader - OpenGL ES 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053731/2-textures-1-shader-opengl-es-2-0)

```
// You could make a "flatter" view by setting nearVal and farVal to a small number
void glOrtho(   GLdouble    left,
    GLdouble    right,
    GLdouble    bottom,
    GLdouble    top,
    GLdouble    nearVal,
    GLdouble    farVal);


CGRect rect = view.bounds;     
glOrthof(-1.0,                                          // Left
      1.0,                                          // Right
     -1.0 / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height),   // Bottom
      1.0 / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height),   // Top
      0.01,                                         // Near
      0.05);                                        // Far

// Then set the viewport
glViewport(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);


// To translate use this PSEUDOCODE
glTranslate( x, y, z);
```

Comment: This is OpenGL ES 1.x code, I strongly advise you not to use (or get used to) it. It is indeed harder to understand at first but infinitely more flexible and (more importantly) faster on modern hardware.

Comment: I looked on OpenGL 2.0 websites to get this code, so that's why I believe it's 2.0.